# Convert a string into array in Shell Script

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell

I am very much new to bash and shell scripting. I have a string like

```
string="new string added -value:ABC-10"
```

Now what I want here is to get the string after -value:.

I am using bash version 5. List of **Things tried**

1. **IFS** methods but that is **syntax error: redirection unexpected**
2. array=(${string//:/ }) this kind of thing
3. while read -r line; do lines+=("$line"); done <<<"$string"
4. string='Paris, France, Europe';
   readarray -td, a <<<"$string"; declare -p a;

Apart from the IFS every other solution is giving **syntax error "(" expected "}"** and I had tried every possible combination for it but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get the part of string after `-value:` __or__ do you want to convert a string to an array? If you want to get the part of the string after `-value:` is the array anyhow relevant in any way?

Comment: Any of the 2 will do the required, but the ultimate goal is to get tha string after -value:  i.e. ABC-10

if it can be converted into array with "-value:"  as delimiter then arr[1] will give the required solution.

or if their is a way to directly get the string after -value: then it would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is direct with bash.
Give a try to :

```
printf "%s\n"  "${string##*-value:}"
```

the man of `bash`:

> ```
>   ${parameter#word}
>   ${parameter##word}
>          Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion, and matched against the expanded value of parameter using the rules  described  under
>          Pattern Matching below.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern
>          (the ``#'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the ``##'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the ex‐
>          pansion  is  the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is
>          the resultant list.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `cut` or `awk`?

```sh
echo "$string" | awk -F '-value:' '{print $2}'
```

With `cut` you can only split on a single character, so with cut it would like like:

```sh
echo "$string" | cut -d ":" -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `IFS` and `read`

```
string="new string added -value:ABC-10"

IFS=: read -r junk value <<< "$string"
echo "$value"
```

With `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a bash4+ feature.

```
mapfile -td: array <<< "$string"
echo "${array[@]:1}"
```

Which is also equivalent to

```
echo "${array[1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are a nice feature, but don't use them if you don't need to. IMO, a simpler way (which also does error checking) is

```
if [[ $string =~ \ -value:(.*)$ ]]
then
  part_after_value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo String does not contain a value parameter 1>&2
fi
```

If you want to treat the case that *-value* is present, but nothing comes after the colon, as an error, replace `.*` by `.+`.